# Is this a neural network

Tags: javascript, algorithm, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I've spent the last 2 days watching youtube videos on neural networks.

In particular, I've been trying to implement a genetic algorithm that will evolve over time, however, most videos seem to be focused on neural networks that are trained, and then used for classification.

Being confused, I decided to simply try to implement the basic structure of the network, and have coded this - in JS, for convenience.

```
function sigmoid (x) { return  1 / (1 + Math.E ** -x); }
function Brain(inputs, hiddens, outputs) {
    this.weights = {
        hidden: [],
        output: []
    };

    for (var i = hiddens; i--;) {
        this.weights.hidden[i] = [];
        for (var w = inputs; w--;) this.weights.hidden[i].push(Math.random());
    }
    for (var i = outputs; i--;) {
        this.weights.output[i] = [];
        for (var w = hiddens; w--;) this.weights.output[i].push(Math.random());
    }
}

Brain.prototype.compute = function(inputs) {
    var hiddenInputs = [];
    for (var i = this.weights.hidden.length; i--;) {
        var dot = 0;
        for (var w = inputs.length; w--;) dot += inputs[w] * this.weights.hidden[i][w];
        hiddenInputs[i] = sigmoid(dot);
    }

    var outputs = [];
    for (var i = this.weights.output.length; i--;) {
        var dot = 0;
        for (var w = this.weights.hidden.length; w--;) dot += hiddenInputs[w] * this.weights.output[i][w];
        outputs[i] = sigmoid(dot);
    }
    return outputs;
}

var brain = new Brain(1,2,1);
brain.compute([1]);
```

I successfully get values between 0 and 1. And, when I use specific weights, I get the same value each time, for a constant input.

1. Is the terminology I'm using in code good?
2. I fear I may simply be observing false positives, and am not actually feeding forward.
3. Is the sigmoid function appropriately? Should I be using it for a genetic / evolving algorithm?

I noticed that I'm getting results only between 0.5 and 1;

Answer (score 1):

To combine a neural network with a genetic algorithm your best shot is probably NEAT. There is a very good implementation of this algorithm in JS called 'Neataptic', you should be able to fint it on github.

When combining GA with ANN you generally want to not only adjust the weights, but the structure as well.

Sigmoid activation is OK for GA, but in many cases you also want other activation functions, you can find a small list of activation functions on wikipedia or create your own ones.